# Will my US Ini files work with European format floating points

Tags: delphi, c++builder, ini

I am using C++Builder XE4 with the Windows 32-bit VCL platform.

I am setting up `.INI` files, which include floating-point numbers that use a period (`.`) for the decimal separator. In Europe they use the comma (`,`) for the decimal separator.

I am using the `TIniFile` class which is built-in to C++Builder.

Will `TIniFile` read the file entries below in Europe?  Do I need a second `.INI` file with the comma as the separator?

When I read the float values, my fail-safe return value also uses the period (`.`). In the code below,

```
ReadFloat("Forex", "Size",  0.01   );
```

0.01 is the fail-safe return value.

Is that going to work in Europe?

For example:

MyList.ini:

```
[Forex]
Size=0.0001
Value=10.5
OffSet=0.01


//Read TIniFile
MyList = new TIniFile("C:\\MyList.ini");
double r_Size = MyList->ReadFloat("Forex", "Size", 0.01);
double r_Value = MyList->ReadFloat("Forex", "Value", 10.0);
double r_OffSet = MyList->ReadFloat("Forex", "OffSet", 0.01);
```

Edit is Below

You indicated in your answer if the TIniFile was written and read in the same location it would read correctly. Would it be possible to open and resave my .INI files one time to convert them to the local format? Then I could use my current code with no change. I would perform the three steps below in a loop for each float in my .INI files. Would this work to reformat the .INI files?

I would only need to adjust the fail-safe return value to use the local Separator.

Step 1) Check Local Value of Separator
Step 2) Load Float using US format (.) Separator
Step 3) Re-Save with local Separator

```
void __fastcall ConvertToLocalSeparator( ){ 

//1 Check Local Value of Seperator
TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
UnicodeString Local = fmt.DecimalSeparator;
UnicodeString Euro    = ",";

if( CompareText(Local, Euro )==0 ){ //Local DecimalSeparator is Coma(,)

//2 Load Float using US format (.) Separator
TFormatSettings USfmt = TFormatSettings::Create(); // get defaults
USfmt.DecimalSeparator = '.';
USfmt.ThousandSeparator = '\0'; //'\0' to disable

TIniFile *MyList;
MyList = new TIniFile("C:\\MyList.ini");
double r_Size = StrToFloatDef(MyList->ReadString("Forex", "Size", ""), 0.01, USfmt);
delete MyList;
MyList=NULL;

//3 Re-Save with local Separator
MyList = new TIniFile("C:\\MyList.ini");
MyList->WriteFloat("Forex", "Size",  r_Size   );
delete MyList;
MyList=NULL;
}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally, `ReadFloat()` uses `ReadString()` and then calls the NON-`TFormatSettings` version of `StrToFloat()` to convert the `String` to a `double`.  Likewise, `WriteFloat()` calls the NON-`TFormatSettings` version of `FloatToStr()` to convert the `double` to a `String` and then calls `WriteString()`.

Those versions of `StrToFloat()` and `FloatToStr()` depend on the global `DecimalSeparator` variable in the `SysUtils` unit, which is locale-dependent.  So **NO**, your existing code will **NOT** work as-is when `ReadFloat()` is called on a system that uses a different locale than the system that calls `WriteFloat()`.

To work around this, you have two choices:

1. change the value of the global `DecimalSeparator` variable to `'.'`.  Not recommended, but can be done.
2. forget `WriteFloat()` and `ReadFloat()` altogether.  Use `WriteString()` and `ReadString()` directly, handling float conversions yourself so you can use whatever fixed formatting you want that is consistent on all systems.

   ```cpp
   //Write TIniFile

   TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create(); // get defaults
   fmt.DecimalSeparator = _D('.');
   fmt.ThousandSeparator = _D(','); // or '\0' to disable

   MyList = new TIniFile(_D("C:\\MyList.ini"));
   MyList->WriteString(_D("Forex"), _D("Size"), FloatToStr(r_Size, fmt));
   MyList->WriteString(_D("Forex"), _D("Value"), FloatToStr(r_Value, fmt));
   MyList->WriteString(_D("Forex"), _D("OffSet"), FloatToStr(r_OffSet, fmt));
   ```

   ```cpp
   //Read TIniFile

   TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
   fmt.DecimalSeparator = _D('.');
   fmt.ThousandSeparator = _D(','); // or '\0' to disable

   MyList = new TIniFile(_D("C:\\MyList.ini"));
   double r_Size = StrToFloatDef(MyList->ReadString(_D("Forex"), _D("Size"), _D("")), 0.01, fmt);
   double r_Value = StrToFloatDef(MyList->ReadString(_D("Forex"), _D("Value"), _D("")), 10.0, fmt);
   double r_OffSet = StrToFloatDef(MyList->ReadString(_D("Forex"), _D("OffSet"), _D("")), 0.01, fmt);
   ```

---

**Update**: if you wanted to read and re-save the file using the local format (which I don't recommend), you could try something more like this:

```cpp
TFormatSettings USFmt;
TFormatSettings EuroFmt;

void __fastcall InitFormats()
{
    USFmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
    USFmt.DecimalSeparator = _D('.');
    USFmt.ThousandSeparator = _D('\0');

    EuroFmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
    EuroFmt.DecimalSeparator = _D(',');
    EuroFmt.ThousandSeparator = _D('\0');
}

void __fastcall CheckLocalFormat(TCustomIniFile *Ini, String Section, String Name, double Default)
{
    double value;
    String s = Ini->ReadString(Section, Name, _D(""));
    if (!TryStrToFloat(s, value))
    {
        if (!TryStrToFloat(s, value, USFmt) && !TryStrToFloat(s, value, EuroFmt))
            value = Default;
        Ini->WriteFloat(Section, Name, value);
    }
}

void __fastcall CheckLocalFormat( )
{
    TIniFile *MyList = new TIniFile(_D("C:\\MyList.ini"));
    CheckLocalFormat(MyList, _D("Forex"), _D("Size"), 0.01);
    CheckLocalFormat(MyList, _D("Forex"), _D("Value"), 10.0);
    CheckLocalFormat(MyList, _D("Forex"), _D("Offset"), 0.01);
    delete MyList;
}
```

Comment: Of course, writing and reading with `TFormatSettings::Invariant` will work too. It will be the same everywhere (more or less the same as the US format settings, AFAIK). Then, there is no need to set the decimal and thousands separators. I'm not sure if that is available in XE4 already, but I'd think so. Otherwise, one can get it using the TFormatSettings constructor.

Comment: I tested this solution on the TMemIniFile as well as the TIniFile and it seems to work correctly with both. Thanks

Comment: Remy, can you explain why you used the _D in your examples? I found limited documentation on this in the Embarcadero wiki dealing with TStringBuilder and don't really understand what it is doing. _D appears to only used with text in quotes " ".

Comment: @homebase `_D()` maps a string/char literal to the data type used natively by the `System::Char` and `System::String` types (currently `wchar_t` on Windows and `char16_t` on other platforms). Your original code was passing Ansi literals to `UnicodeString` parameters, which incurs data conversions at run-time. Passing a literal in the native format avoids a data conversion. `_D()` is the Delphi equivalent of `_T()` in the C runtime library and `TEXT()` in the Win32 API. `_D()` was introduced in C++Builder 2009 when the entire RTL and VCL were switched to Unicode, but it is still not widely used